# How to get registered services in integration test

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I want to add an ApplicationUser user in my integration test, so i need to use ‘UserManager.CreateAsync()’.
I already know how to get the ApplicationDbContext, from the ‘integration testing’ docs page.

My question is how do i get the UserManager service in the integration test or any other di registered service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve it via `TestServer`.

```
var testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseEnvironment("Development"));

var myService = testServer.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
```